# How do i do this in rxjava 2?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

parents have children.  children have test ids.  each test ids corresponds to a test score.  I want each child to have a list of their test scores.

getParentObservable(): `Observable<Parent>`

getChildrenSingle(val parentId: Int): `Single<List<Child>>`

Child contains `List<Int>` testIds and a `List<Score>` scores that I want to fill

getScoresSingle(val testId: Int): `Single<Score>`

I've tried the following with unexpected results:

```
// children is a class level var List<Child>
var childIndex = 0
getParentObservable()
.flatMap { parent -> getChildrenSingle(parent.Id) }
.flatMapObservable { kids ->
  children = kids
  Observable.fromIterable(kids)
}
.flatMap { kid -> Observable.fromIterable(kid.testIds) }
.flatMapSingle { testId -> getScoresSingle(testId) }
.toList()
.compose(IoMainThreadScheduler)
.subscribe { currentKidsScores ->
  children[childIndex].scores = currentKidsScores
  childIndex = childIndex + 1
}
```

Here is an illustration of what it could look like:

```
Parent1
   -->Child 1
      -->TestId1
         -->TestScore1
   -->Child2
     -->TestId1
        -->TestScore1
     -->TestId2
        -->TestScore2
Parent2
   -->Child 1
      -->TestId1
         -->TestScore1
```

I want onSuccess to be called 3 times, 1 per child.  Inside onSuccess the child should be assigned his or her Scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onSuccess()` will not be called 3 times because `toList()` call returns a `Single` and a `Single` emits at most once. Try this:

```
getParentObservable() // Observable<Parent>
   .flatMapSingle { parent ->
       getChildrenSingle(parent.Id) // Single<List<Child>>
   } // Observable<List<Child>>
   .flatMap { children ->
       Observable.fromIterable(children) // Observable<Child>
   } // Observable<Child>
   .flatMapSingle { child ->
       Observable.fromIterable(child.testIds) // Observable<Int>
           .flatMapSingle { testId ->
               getScoresSingle(testId)
           } // Observable<Score>
           .toList() // Single<List<Score>>
           .map { scores ->
               child.scores = scores
               child
           } // Single<Child>
   } // Observable<Child>
   .compose(IoMainThreadScheduler)
   .subscribe { child ->
       // Do stuff this will called 3 times, 1 time for each child
   }
```